# Only loop part of result

Tags: php, sql, loops, select

I'm fairly new to PHP/SQL and I'm aware that this maybe a basic question but I cannot find the answer. I am successfully returning an array of results from the following query however, I only want part of the returned data to loop:

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con,"
SELECT LastName 
AS sLast, FirstName
AS sFirst, b.date AS
dDate, b.name AS
dName, a.wk1places
AS eWk1
FROM students
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id, name, wk1places
    FROM employers)
    a ON a.id = $e_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id, date, name
    FROM dates)
    b ON b.id = 1
WHERE WK1 = a.name");
$wk1 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <div style="float:left">
        Week <?php echo $row['dName'] ;?><br>
        <?php echo $row['dDate'] ;?>
        <!-- THIS DATA TO LOOP -->
        <p>
            <?php echo $row['sLast'] ;?>, <?php echo $row['sFirst'] ;?>
        </p>
        <!-- / -->
        <?php echo $wk1 ?> / <?php echo $row['eWk1'] ;?>   

<?php }?>
```

The code enclosed in `<p>` should loop, but the echoed rows above and below should stay the same and not be duplicated. Any help would be much appreciated!! Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean with: "should stay the same"? They contain dynamic values. Please show the expected outcome.

Comment: Extract the first row outside the `while` loop.

Comment: @colburton The only values that change are sLast and sFirst. All other values stay the same and are therefore duplicated. I only want them to display once.

Comment: @Phil: They are from `$row` which makes them dynamic.

Comment: @colburton Is there a way to stop them from looping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `do while` loop after doing the first read of the results outside the loop, you can capture the 2 repeated fields from the first read and then just loop over the data selecting from it what you wish to use.

As the while test is done at the end of the loop and not the beginning the first row gets processed as part of the read of the result that you do outside the loop, and only the 2 fields you are interested in in the loop are used in the code inside the loop.

```
$wk1  = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ( $wk1 > 0 ) :

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $eWk1 = $row['eWk1'];

    echo '<div style="float:left">Week ';

    echo $row['dName'] . '<br>' . $row['dDate'];

    do {
        echo '<p>' . $row['sLast'] . ', ' . $row['sFirst'] . '</p>';
    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));

    echo $wk1 . ' / ' . $eWk1;
endif;

?>
```

Comment: This works too. Is this a more efficient way than @Danijel's suggestion?

Comment: I would say 6 of one and half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 0):

It makes little sense to only loop part of the results.

What you should do here is change your SQL query to return only the data that you need, so that the loop is efficient.

So concentrate on your SQL query:

```
SELECT LastName 
AS sLast, FirstName
AS sFirst, b.date AS
dDate, b.name AS
dName, a.wk1places
AS eWk1
FROM students
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id, name, wk1places
    FROM employers)
    a ON a.id = $e_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id, date, name
    FROM dates)
    b ON b.id = 1
WHERE WK1 = a.name"
```

and add extra clauses that limit the data.

Comment: This might be a daft question, but how do you LIMIT a LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

It seams you want this:

```
$wk1 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$html = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    $dName = $row['dName'];
    $dDate = $row['dDate'];
    $eWk1 = $row['eWk1'];
    <!-- THIS DATA TO LOOP -->
    $html .= '<p>'.$row['sLast'].', '.$row['sFirst'].'</p>';
    <!-- / -->
<?php } ?>

<div style="float:left">
    Week <?php echo $dName; ?><br>
    <?php echo $dDate; ?>
    <?php echo $html;?>
    <?php echo $wk1 ?> / <?php echo $eWk1; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all values are the same except `sLast` and `sFirst` then take the first row to output data before and after loop, and use `data_seek(0)` to reset mysql result.

```
$wk1 = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$first_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
    <div style="float:left">
        Week <?php echo $first_row['dName'] ;?><br>
        <?php echo $first_row['dDate'] ;?>
<?php
$result->data_seek(0);
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { ?>
        <p>
            <?php echo $row['sLast'] ;?>, <?php echo $row['sFirst'] ;?>
        </p>
<?php } ?>

<?php echo $wk1; ?> / <?php echo $first_row['eWk1']; ?>
```